# REST endpoint for complex actions

Tags: rest, model, architecture, request, endpoint

I have a REST API which serves data from the database to the frontend React app and to Android app.
The API have multiple common endpoints for each model:
- `GET    /model/<id>` to retrieve a single object
- `POST   /model` to create
- `PATCH  /model/<id>` to update a single model
- `GET    /model` to list objects
- `DELETE /model/<id>` to delete an object

Currently I'm developing an Android app and I find such scheme to make me do many extra requests to the API. For example, each Order object has a user_creator entry. So, if I want to delete all the orders created by specified user I need to
1) List all users `GET /user`
2) Select the one I need
3) List all orders he created `GET /order?user=user_id`
4) Select the order I want to delete
5) Delete the order `DELETE /order/<id>`

I'm wondering whether this will be okay to add several endpoints like `GET /order/delete?user=user_id`. By doing this I can get rid of action 4 and 5. And all the filtering will be done at the backend. However it seems to me as a bad architecture solution because all the APIs I've used before don't have such methods and all the filtering, sorting and other "beautifying" stuff is usually at the API user side, not the backend.

In your answer please offer a solution that is the best in your opinion for this problem and explain your point of view at least in brief, so I can learn from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your problem is in isolation:

- You have an Order collection and a User collection
- User 1..* Orders
- You want to delete all orders for a given user ID

I would use the following URI:

```
// delete all orders for a given user
POST /users/:id/orders/delete
```

Naturally, this shows the relationship between Users & Orders and is self-explanatory that you are only dealing with orders associated with a particular user. Also, given the operation will result in side-effects on the server then you should POST rather than GET (reading a resource should never change the server). The same logic could be used to create an endpoint for pulling only user orders e.g.

```
// get all orders for a given user
GET /users/:id/orders
```

Answer (score -1):

The application domain of HTTP is the transfer of documents over a network.  Your "REST API" is a facade that acts like a document store, and performs useful work as a *side effect* of transferring documents.  See [Jim Webber (2011)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).

So the basic idioms are that we post a document, or we send a bunch of edits to an existing document, and the server interprets those changes and does something useful.

So a simple protocol, based on the existing remote authoring semantics, might look like

```
GET /orders?user=user_id

Make local edits to the representation of that list provided by the server

PUT /orders?user=user_id
```

The semantics of how to do that are something that needs to be understood by both ends of the exchange.  Maybe you remove unwanted items from the list?  Maybe there is a status entry for each record in the list, and you change the status from active to expired.

On the web, instead of remote authoring semantics we tend to instead use form submissions.  You get a blank form from somewhere, you fill it out yourself, you post it to the indicated inbox, and the person responsible for processing that inbox does the work.

So we load a blank form into our browser, and we make our changes to it, and then we post it to the resource listed in the form.

```
GET /the-blank-form?user=user_id

Make changes in the form...

POST ????
```

What should the target-uri be?  The web browser doesn't care; it is just going to submit the form to whatever target is specified by the representation it received.  One answer might be to send it right back where we got it:

```
POST /the-blank-form?user=user_id
```

And that works fine (as long as you manage the metadata correctly).  Another possibility is to instead send the changes to the resource you expect to reflect those changes:

```
POST /orders?user=user_id
```

and it turns out *that* works fine too.  HTTP has interesting [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) semantics built into the specification, so we can make sure the client's stale copy or the orders collection resource is invalidated by using that same resource as the target of the POST call.

> Currently my API satisfies the table from the bottom of the REST, so, any extra endpoint will break it. Will it be fatal or not, that's the question.

No, it will be fine -- just add/extend a POST handler on the appropriate resource to handle the new semantics.

Longer answer: the table in wikipedia is a good representation of common practices; but common practices aren't quite on the mark.  Part of the problem is that REST includes a *uniform interface*.  Among other things, that means that all resources understand the same message semantics.  The notion of "collection resources" vs "member resources" doesn't exist in REST -- the semantics are the same for both.

Another way of saying this is that a general-purpose component never knows if the resource it is talking to is a collection or a member.  All unsafe methods (POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE/etc) imply [invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) of the representations of the target-uri.

Now POST, as it happens, means "do something that hasn't been standardized" -- see [Fielding 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).  It's the method that has the fewest semantic constraints.

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics. -- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)

It's perfectly fine for a POST handler to branch based on the contents of the request payload; if you see X, create something, if you see Y delete something else.  It's analogous to having two different web forms, with different semantics, that submit to the same target resource.

Comment: Ok, I think what you are trying to say is that variations in the data server sends to client and backwards may be different from case to case, same may be the changes done on the backend. That's the good point I shall use. However, more specifically, my question was whether it is okay to add an extra endpoint to one model and not add it to others. Currently my API satisfies the table from the bottom of the [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), so, any extra endpoint will break it. Will it be fatal or not, that's the question. If yes, what is the workaround?

Comment: I had to downvote this answer, it is entirely unclear what the point is and how it relates to REST best practices. I get a feeling that the answer intends to say "Do what you want/need to do and don't worry about it", but the reasoning behind this is entirely unclear.